# Erro de Locale / ORA-01843: not a valid month / JVM language

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jvm

Estou rodando uma aplicação que é um `microserviço` feito em `Spring Boot`.

Ao executar um código local, ele consegue obter os dados do banco. É a geração de um relatório que busca dados no `banco oracle` que está setado as configurações como `pt/BR` em geral.

```sql
SELECT * FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS;
```

Resultado:

```
NLS_LANGUAGE    BRAZILIAN PORTUGUESE
NLS_TERRITORY   BRAZIL
NLS_CURRENCY    R$
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    BRAZIL
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  ,.
NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD/MM/RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   BRAZILIAN PORTUGUESE
NLS_SORT    WEST_EUROPEAN
NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH24:MI:SSXFF
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF
```

Eu faço o deploy no jenkins após commit. E a aplicação é colocada no kubernetes.

Ele gera o erro `Caused by: java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: not a valid month`

Ao ler o `locale default`, do código no servidor, eu percebi que ele está com default `Locale default: en_US`

Eu já tentei mudar o locale de algumas maneiras.

Uma delas foi no `application.yml`:

```
spring.mvc.locale: pt_BR
```

Já tentei setar programaticamente após a aplicação subir:

```
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void doSomethingAfterStartup() {
        Locale.setDefault(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
        System.out.println("LocaleConfig | Locale Setted");
        System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());
    }
```

E de fato, quando leio o locale no início do método do controller que recebe a requisição, ele já está setado como pt/BR.

```
2021-10-25 12:54:08.913  INFO 1 --- [or-http-epoll-3] b.c.u.a.v1.controller.MonthlyController  : MonthlyController / Locale for generate excel: pt_BR
```

Mesmo assim continua apresentando o mesmo erro:

```
2021-10-25 12:54:10.130  WARN 1 --- [or-http-epoll-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1843, SQLState: 22008
2021-10-25 12:54:10.131 ERROR 1 --- [or-http-epoll-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema foi resolvido adicionando os parâmetros da JVM no pipeline do servidor.

`-Duser.country=BR -Duser.language=pt`

De outras maneiras, conforme acima, não conseguia resolver.